# Exclude data points with geographic coordinates that are located too far from a specific set of coordinates

Tags: r

I am struggling with the following. I have a large data frame (25 000rows x 500 columns) with geographic coordinates on the one hand and corresponding presence/absence data of species at each particular coordinate on the other (as in the example data frame below).

I need to link positive occurrences of species to observed negative occurrences of species in a particular radius around positive occurrences (let's say 25km). In other words: I want to get rid of data points with absences of species that are geographically too far located from sites where the species ís present.

I would draw a buffer of 25km around each coordinate that corresponds with a positive occurrence of a species, i.e. around all coordinates in the data frame that correspond with '1' as occurrence value.

Then I would want to extract all data points with a negative occurrence, i.e. '0' as occurrence value, that have geographic coordinates that fall within the buffer zones of the positive occurrences to a new data frame. Then merge this new data frame containing only absence-points near points where species are present with a data frame containing only presence data.

Unfortunately, I have very little experience programming in R but the size of my dataset obligates me to find an R-solution. I would be much obliged if anyone can help me.

```
df <- data.frame(LON = c('2.593014360', '2.959084082', '4.333446258', '2.593014352'), 
                  LAT = c('51.08509738', '51.1209541', '48.36202696', '51.08509741'),
                  SPECIES1 = c('1', '0', '1', '0'),
                  SPECIES2 = c('0', '0', '1', '0'),
                  SPECIES3 = c('1', '1', '0', '0'))
```

Comment: I'd consider looking at `sf::st_buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with sp, sf libraries

```r
library(sp)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.2, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
#> Google's Terms of Service: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/.
#> Please cite ggmap if you use it! See citation("ggmap") for details.
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- data.frame(LON = c('2.593014360', '2.959084082', '4.333446258', '2.593014352'), 
                 LAT = c('51.08509738', '51.1209541', '48.36202696', '51.08509741'),
                 SPECIES1 = c('1', '0', '1', '0'),
                 SPECIES2 = c('0', '0', '1', '0'),
                 SPECIES3 = c('1', '1', '0', '0'))


df[, 1:2] <- sapply(df[, 1:2], as.numeric)

species <- sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = df[c("LON", "LAT")], data = df)
species <- st_as_sf(species)
species1 <- species %>% filter(SPECIES1 == 1) %>% st_union() %>% st_buffer(dist = 1)

ggplot(species1) +
  geom_sf()
```

Please note, st_buffer(dist = x) is in CRS dimmension. In this case in degree, not in (kilo)meters. You have to convert it to one of meters-system. For details you can check https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311502/how-to-use-st-buffer

Regards,
Grzegorz